How to write route in link_to?
I use active storage and active text. I attach image and write text. Rails creates posts with image and text. ative storage created file _blob.html.erb. I add link_to and path to 3 line:
<figure class="attachment attachment--<%= blob.representable? ? "preview" : "file" %> attachment--<%= blob.filename.extension %>">
  <% if blob.representable? %>
    <%= link_to image_tag blob.representation(resize_to_limit: local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] : [ 1024, 768 ]), news_path(@new)%>
  <% end %>

  <figcaption class="attachment__caption">
    <% if caption = blob.try(:caption) %>
      <%= caption %>
    <% else %>
      <span class="attachment__name"><%= blob.filename %></span>
      <span class="attachment__size"><%= number_to_human_size blob.byte_size %></span>
    <% end %>
  </figcaption>
</figure>

But I click image I get errror:
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"news", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]

I want to redirect to show view by clicking on image. How to solve this problem?

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem


I want to redirect to show view by clicking on image. How to solve this problem?

I assume here is the right syntax for this:
<%= link_to news_path(@new) do %>
  <%= image_tag blob.representation(resize_to_limit: local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] : [ 1024, 768 ]) %>
<% end %>

Check documentation.

But I click image I get error ... No route matches ... , missing required keys: [:id]

Please make sure that object which you pass to news_path helper (@new) does have an id.
For example add this line above you link_to code:
<% raise 'During debug I have found that my @new does not have id!!' if @new.id.nil? %>


News is uncountable - the singular form isn't @new it's @news.

True! But I've just got it from author's code: the variable being used in view is @new.

ah you're right. The issue could also be that @new is nil which I would kind of expect if you use the generators as it will properly singularize news.

I don't have @new in _blob.html.erb. How to make it?

what about 3d line? <%= link_to ..., news_path(@new)%>
